# wordpress and add actions to button by coding

Tags: ajax

I create my action in functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function'); // wp_ajax_{ACTION HERE} 
 function misha_filter_function()
 {
   echo "my button action"; 
 }
```

How can i create button to call this method `wp_ajax_myfilter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below method.

```
<a id="view_site_description" href="javascript:void(0);">View Our Site Description</a>

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_js_to_wp_footer' );
function add_js_to_wp_footer(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#view_site_description').click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {"action": "myfilter"},
            success: function(data){alert(data);}
        });
        return false;
    });
    </script>
<?php }
```